# Why is my array reading zero, retrieving values from a 2d array in a function javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have a function that generates a 2d array. but when I'm trying to receive elements out of the 2d array I get 'undefined'. How do I get element out of the 2d array from the function? I notice that all my array reads zero when there is something clearly in them how do I change this?

**HERE THE CODE**

```
//The function prints the 2d array 
console.log(playerCal( 7, 5));

    //Trying to access elements in the array
    var rec = playerCal(7 , 5);
    var print = rec[1][0];
    console.log(print);
```

There is clearly something in the array what happening?

[image]

Comment: can you post the declaration for the array?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: It would be helpful to show what happens in the playerCal() function since it is apparently passing back an array that is structured differently than you are expecting.

Comment: The playCal() function print the array as shown in the image and undefined is the print variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I can't return values in ajax. So it was returning zero.

You are using Ajax incorrectly, the idea is not to have it return anything, but instead hand off the data to something called a callback function, which handles the data.

```
function handleData( responseData ) {
    // do what you want with the data
    console.log(responseData);
}

$.ajax({
    url: "hi.php",
    ...
    success: function ( data, status, XHR ) {
        handleData(data);
    }
});
```

returning anything in the submit handler will not do anything, you must instead either hand off the data, or do what you want with it directly inside the success function.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT Read your question wrong, the image cleared it up for me.

Do console.log on rec, not on print. according to your image its saying that print (which is set to rec[1][0]) is a multi dimensional array which has a valid value for print[1][0]

so I think rec is not set to what you think it may be.